# table "" does not exist, skipping, table is not mapped

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, docker

I am trying to build app on Spring boot, with postgres. I am using docker-compose. 
I got an error when I tried to access data 
Here is exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: table is not mapped [SELECT t FROM table t WHERE t.code = :code]
app_1         |     at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:138)
app_1         |     at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181)
app_1         |     at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:188)
app_1         |     at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:718)
app_1         |     at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:809)
app_1         |     at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:23)
```

Method TableRepository

```
    public Table getDataByCode(String tc) {
        try {
            TypedQuery<Table> q = em.createQuery("SELECT t FROM table t WHERE t.code = :code", Table.class);
            q.setParameter("code", tc);
            return q.getSingleResult();
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

function is called by
**Table t = tableRepository.getDataByCode("CCC");**

My Entity Table

```
package hello.world.entity;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="table")
public class Table {
    @Id
    @Column(name="code", length=3, nullable=false)
    private String code;

    @Column(name="name", length=256, nullable=false)
    private String name;

    public Table() {
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, you should give more information. For example, the Controller/Service classes of Spring Boot, the Entity class, perhaps the structure of the database table. For what purpose are you using docker-compose? You should add more details because your request is too generic.

Comment: @A.Wolf I edited post

Comment: Does the application connects to the database?Have you tried to do a `findAll()`? Please add also the code of your Repository.

Comment: I would recommend you change your entity name from `table` to another name because it seems to be a reserved name and it might be dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the `SELECT` from a table with a specific field implementing the `JpaRepository` interface and using the `findByField(...)` definition, where `Field` is the name of the actual field you want to add in the `WHERE` clause. 
If you want to do select by code, you can do the following:

```
@Repository
public interface TableRepository extends JpaRepository<Table, String> {

    List<Table> findByCode(String code);

}
```

In this way you don't have to add the implementation of the code, Jpa will take care of it for you.
Then you can call it simply like this:

```
Table t = tableRepository.findByCode("CCC");
```

---

Remember that you should have in your application.properties file some properties like these to connect to your database:

```
## Spring DATASOURCE (DataSourceAutoConfiguration & DataSourceProperties)
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres_demo
spring.datasource.username= rajeevkumarsingh
spring.datasource.password=

# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

As you can find in [this article for example](https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-jpa-hibernate-postgresql-restful-crud-api-example/).

Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: how to check if app connected to postgres?

Comment: You should see it in the log file. To do a simple check, add some data to the table directly on the database and call `tableRepository.findAll()`. It will return those results.

Comment: I think my app is not connected to postgre, when I do docker run postgres, there is a message on console  **listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432**. Should it be like 127.0.0.0:5432?

Comment: You should also add the docker-compose file.. Is your Spring Boot application in another container?

Comment: Yes I have docker compose file. Yes spring boot in another container

Comment: You should add the docker-compose file content to your question :)